wpforms loader for element clikc event when cliking on dropdown or radio button
I am facing issue with wpforms. I have used lots of conditional logic in my forms and form is very slow now. Page load faster but takes long time to show conditional fields. If there any way to add loader in form click event (when click on conditional parent dropdown)?
https://bizzhopper.com/start-your-registration/ this is the form
